# Finding all possible integer solutions to an equation with 3 variables

Tags: python

I'm very new to python and wanted to solve an equation to practice and learn.  Unfortunately I couldn't even begin to solve this equation:

- x,y,z are positive single digit (sorry I forgot to include this in my original question) integers

10*x+y = 2*x + 2*y + z

I know that if x=1 and y= 6 then z must be 2. Can anyone help me find a list of all integer solutions that work using python?

It seems simple to me, but I just started learning python and I don't think I have the vocabulary to solve this.  I think I can solve it using English but I don't know the proper python.

For example, I want to say: Let x,y,z = positive intergers -> 10*x+y = 2*x + 2*y + z -> Solve for [x,y,z]

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: *z = 8x - y*. Why have you written it in the way you have? Clearly there are a countable infinite number of integral solutions. Which ones don't you want?

Comment: I want to limit the equation to single digit integers! I'm sorry i forgot to include that!

Comment: If you want specific solution, you need 3 unique equations for 3 variables problem, if you want list of integers, you need to specify the range for the solution, otherwise, it just has infinite number of integral solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After simplifying your equation, it resolves to : `8x-y-z = 0`

You can use list comprehension to get the solution in the given range of values i.e. single digit solution

```py
[(x,y,z) for x in range(10) for y in range(10) for z in range(10) if (8*x-y-z)==0]
Out[68]: 
[(0, 0, 0),
 (1, 0, 8),
 (1, 1, 7),
 (1, 2, 6),
 (1, 3, 5),
 (1, 4, 4),
 (1, 5, 3),
 (1, 6, 2),
 (1, 7, 1),
 (1, 8, 0),
 (2, 7, 9),
 (2, 8, 8),
 (2, 9, 7)]
```

Or
If you don't want to manually resolve it, You can split it into left right and apply the logic:

```py
expression = '10*x+y = 2*x + 2*y + z'
lhs, rhs = expression.split('=')
[(x,y,z) for x in range(10) for y in range(10) for z in range(10) if eval(lhs)==eval(rhs)]
Out[69]: 
[(0, 0, 0),
 (1, 0, 8),
 (1, 1, 7),
 (1, 2, 6),
 (1, 3, 5),
 (1, 4, 4),
 (1, 5, 3),
 (1, 6, 2),
 (1, 7, 1),
 (1, 8, 0),
 (2, 7, 9),
 (2, 8, 8),
 (2, 9, 7)]
```

Answer (score 0):

For solving these type of mathematical equation. I prefer to use [SymPy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/gotchas.html#:%7E:text=SymPy%20is%20nothing%20more%20than,standard%20library%20sys%20or%20re%20.&text=It%20also%20means%20that%20SymPy,familiar%20with%20programming%20with%20Python.), which make simple to understand and to solve.

10x + y = 2x + 2y + z

8x - y -z = 0

```
from sympy import *  # import python library
x, y, z = symbols(['x', 'y', 'z']) # define all variables with its symbols
system = [
    Eq(8*x - y -z, 0)
]                              
soln = solve(system, [x, y, z])
print(soln)
output>>{x: y/8 + z/8}
```

Comment: Can you add context around this answer to make it more useful for others?

Answer (score 0):

There is a library designed for this kind of stuff: [python-constraint](https://pypi.org/project/python-constraint/)

this is a solution for your problem

```
from constraint import *

problem = Problem()
problem.addVariables(['x', 'y', 'z'], range(100))
problem.addConstraint(lambda x, y, z: 10*x+y == 2*x + 2*y + z, ('x', 'y', 'z'))
solutions = problem.getSolutions()

print(solutions)
```